# How to count occurrence of alphabet in python?

Tags: python, string

I have written a custom python code to count the occurrence of an alphabet after a certain alphabet. For example, in my case, I have a string "ABACCD". Now I want to find that starting with alphabet "A", in my string, how many times it is followed by "B", how many times it is followed by "C" etc. Similarly for "B" as well, how many time it is followed by "A", how many time it is followed by "B", how many times it is followed by "C". So the output will be something like: If my alphabet is "A", it is being followed by "A" zero times, it is being followed by "B" 1 time, followed by "C" 1 time and followed by "D" 0 times.
The code that I have written just return me a list of 1s. Here is my code:

```
s = "ABACCD"
a = []

for i in s:
    if(i=="A"):
        for j in s:
            a_count = 0
            if(j=="A"):
                a_count+=1
                a.append(a_count)
print(a)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Since it's not clear to me what you're asking for, would you please rewrite your question so that you show your desired output (or two) versus your actual output?

Comment: An easy way to gaet a count of all pairs: `from collections import Counter;
print(Counter(zip(s, s[1:])))`

Answer (score 0):

It's better of use a dictionary than a list to keep track of all the pairs of letter occurences

**1. Basic Python using dictionary**

```
cnts = {}
for a, b in zip(s, s[1:]):
    cnts[(a,b)] = cnts.get((a, b), 0) + 1

print(cnts) # {('A', 'B'): 1, ('B', 'A'): 1, ('A', 'C'): 1, ('C', 'C'): 1, ('C', 'D'): 1}
```

**2. Basic Python without zip**

```
cnts = {}
i = 0
while i < len(s) - 1:
    a = s[i]
    b = s[i+1]
    cnts[(a,b)] = cnts.get((a, b), 0) + 1
    i += 1    
print(cnts)
#{('A', 'B'): 1, ('B', 'A'): 1, ('A', 'C'): 1, ('C', 'C'): 1, ('C', 'D'): 1}
```

**3. Solution using collections.Counter**

```
from collections import Counter
cnts = Counter(zip(s, s[1:]))
print(cnts) 
#Counter({('A', 'B'): 1,
          ('B', 'A'): 1,
          ('A', 'C'): 1,
          ('C', 'C'): 1,
          ('C', 'D'): 1})
```